# Why UITableView with autoresizing row height "scrolls up and then down" when loading more rows from remote server?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift4

I have a `UITableView` with varying labels length in each row, so in my `viewDidLoad` I include this code to resize the table view row automatically according to its content:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
```

With a fixed number of rows this is absolutely fine. But in my case the number of rows can become big at times, so I show 15 rows at a time to go a little quicker.

This is where I ask for more data from the remote server, in `UITableViewDelegate` method `tableView(_:willDisplay:forRowAt:)`

The problem is that when I insert a new set of rows, the table view kinda shakes up and down and a user would get lost where he/ she was in the table before new items were loaded.

The way I insert new rows into the table view is as follows:

```
func insertRowsInSection(_ tableView: UITableView, newObjects: [Object]) {
    var indexPaths = [IndexPath]()
    let lastRowPlusOne = tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0)

    if newObjects.count >= 1 {
        for objectIndex in 0...newObjects.count - 1 {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: objectIndex + lastRowPlusOne, section: 0)
            indexPaths.append(indexPath)
        }

        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            tableView.performBatchUpdates({
                tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .automatic)
            }, completion: nil)
        } else {
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .automatic)
            tableView.endUpdates()
        }
    }
}
```

I must say that when fixing the row height to a specific value this "shaking" behavior is not there at all.

Answer (score 5):

This is the issue of autosizing cell together with UITableView. UITableView will calculate it contentSize based on your estimatedHeight. Eg.

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
```

this mean if you have 15 rows, your "estimated" tableView's contentSize will be around 1500px + (other possible like section header), but actual contentSize will be recalculated based on displayed cells after you scroll pass them. Then when you call

```
tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .automatic)
```

it will perform animation to contentSize by using those estimatedSize (also your newly added cells will be calculated by estimatedSize) which mean it's not precise calculation which cause jumpy animation.

The best solution is.... go with manual calculate height with exact cell height return by UITableViewDelegate

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
```

This will be a lot more work and break all purposes of autolayout with UITableViewCell. But it will give you very precise insert/delete/reload animation on UITableView. You still can use autolayout inside your cell but also include manual calculation for elements' margin or text size.

Another workaround is caching your cell height.

```
var cellHeights: [IndexPath: CGFloat] = [:]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    guard let height = cellHeights[indexPath] else {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
    return height
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,  willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell,  forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cellHeight[indexPath] = cell.frame.height
}
```

This will help you as workaround but it's the solution 100% solution for animation issue. I still go with manual height calculation if I want to use nice smooth tableView animation.

Comment: How would you calculate the height of a cell in `tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)` while the height depends on the on the number of lines for 2 labels?

Comment: You have to manage it manually, example is in your cell your may want to have function to calculate the height based on width and texts

`static func calculateHeight(labelOneText: String, labelTwoText: String, inWidth width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat { // calculdate height }`

You may use [boundingRect](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1524729-boundingrect) to calculate the text size then + spacing value.

Comment: Thanks. It's indeed a tedious process to calculate it. Particularly when your `UITableViewCell` has a custom `accessoryView` and two nested `UIStackView` - Anyway, I made the row height calculation but still have the jumpy table view?!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you dispatch to main queue when calling your `insertRowsInSection` method and implement `heightForRowAt indexPath` based on the text length.
Your label/s must have a fixed width, if only height should autoresize. 
e.g. assuming you have two labels stacked vertically with some padding in between:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    // get label1Text and label2Text from data-source 
    // get label widths and the font used in the labels
    let label1Height = label1Text.heightForFixed(width: label1Width, font: label1Font)
    let label2Height = label2Text.heightForFixed(width: label2Width, font: label2Font)

    return label1Height + label2Height + padding // the padding you want between the labels.
}
```

Helper `String` extension to calculate bounding size for text length:

```
extension String {

    func heightForFixed(width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        let container = CGSize(width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let rect = self.boundingRect(with: container, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [.font: font], context: nil)

        return ceil(rect.height)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I still get the jumpy table view?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue from what you mentioned, simulating updates from network fetch and inserting items. There must be something else you're doing you have not mentioned.

Comment: This works perfectly on one table view with a cell containing a vertical stack view with two labels a horizontal stack view with another 3 nested horizontal stack views each with a label and a fixed size image. The other table view is still shaking so there must be something I had done earlier with the constraints?!